# What is system.size_estimates in cassandra and plausible reasons behind high disk consumption

Tags: cassandra, cql, spark-cassandra-connector, nodetool, distributed-database

I've been using cassandra on two nodes where one of them ran out of disk space and went down. When I checked, I've observed the size of size_estimates to be ~30GB.

I've removed sstable files from my data directories and restarted the node. Was curious about the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, the `size_estimates` contains estimates of partition counts and their corresponding size. The estimates are calculated and recorded in the background every 5 minutes.

You haven't provided enough information in your post to determine why the node ran out of space. You'll need to analyse the logs for clues. Cheers!

Comment: Can you please help me with the cause behind observation (size of size_estimates to be ~30GB) and if you need any information that helps you suggest an approach?